# Python 2.7: Accessing value from dictionary using string

Tags: python, string

I am having issues accessing a value from a dictionary.

Example:

```
str = 'str1','str2'
dict={str:1}
str1 = 'str1'
str2='str2'
str1+"','"+str2)
```

returns `'str1','str2'`

```
dict.get(str1+"','"+str2) # does not return the value.
```

Criteria:

- I cannot use `str` to retrieve the value from `dict`
- I have to concatenate `str1` and `str2`

Can someone please help.

Comment: You are not showing us working code, nor any code that shows how you produce your printed output.

Comment: I see. This is work related so I need to protect IP. I will get something up that abstracts the code a bit.

Comment: However, the code that you posted will not produce the output you claim to see, you'll need to produce a short piece of code that actually produces the problematic output.

Comment: Whoa. You replaced the whole question with a different one

Comment: essentially the same problem. I am actually not sure if the \\ is the issue. The thing is I cannot retrieve the value from dict by concatenating two strings together

Comment: Your code changed dramatically. Your `str` key is **not** a string, it's a tuple with two strings contained.

Comment: You just need to use `dict.get((str1, str2))`. And don't use `dict` as a variable name even in examples.

Comment: @SeekingAlpha, it's a different question. Someone coming along now will have a tough time seeing how the answers relate to this question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command

```
str = 'str1','str2'
```

creates a tuple in the variable `str`, and is equivalent to doing

```
str = ('str1', 'str2')
```

Note that this is probably the underlying cause of your confusion... you are creating a tuple but putting it in a variable with a name that indicates you expected a string.

When you do

```
str1 = 'str1'
str2 = 'str2'
dict.get(str1+"','"+str2)
# The above is equivalent to
# mystr = str1+"','"+str2
# dict.get(mystr)
```

you are trying to access the key `"str1','str2"`, which is not in the dictionary.  You want to access the tuple `('str1', 'str2')`.

To do this, try

```
str1 = 'str1'
str2 = 'str2'
mytuple = str1, str2 # or mytuple = (str1, str2)
dict.get(mytuple)
# or dict.get((str1, str2)) # Note the extra parentheses
```

---

I am obliged to say that `str` and `dict` are bad names for a variables because they shadow the python builtin functions `str` and `dict`.

Answer (score 0):

`"','".join([driver1.name, driver2.name])` will add ',' between the two names.